# Linking iOS reminders and Alexa lists

Tags: ios, cloudkit, alexa-skills-kit

I apologize if this is the wrong place or too vague, but I’m not sure where else to start.

I’d like to build a server side script that pulls anything I add to my Alexa shopping list and adds it to my iOS reminders list of the same name, and then deletes it from the Alexa list.

Unfortunately, everything I’ve found uses IFTT, which is unreliable.

I’m not sure where to begin, or if this is even possible. Anyone know if this is even possible? If it is, I’d be grateful for some pointers.